# stay login laravel 9

Tags: laravel, authentication, basic-authentication, laravel-9

can't stay login in project,

this is my code in appserviceprovider.php ,

```
    Auth::loginUsingId(18876 ,true);
```

is true and login and get ,

```
    dd(auth()->user()->id);
```

my output,

```
^ 18876
```

this picture,
[image]

and my export in website user is loggedin,
[image]
if comment this
`Auth::loginUsingId(18876 ,true);`
and write dd(auth()->user()->id);
[image]
and check user is login

```
  if (Auth::check()) {
        dd(1);
    } else {
        dd(2);
    }
```

output

[image]

Comment: Is middleWhere auth added to this route?

Comment: not have  @WaelKhalifa

Comment: Could you please dd(Auth::loginUsingId(18876 ,true));

Comment: @WaelKhalifa 
 showed user information

Comment: auth()->user() will only work after the AuthServiceProvider has ran

Comment: This will all depend on when a model is actually created or updated. auth()->user() will only work after the AuthServiceProvider has ran and (if you are using the session authentication) the StartSession middleware has been executed. If you create or update a model before this happens (e.g. a controller constructor) then auth()->user() will be nulL

Comment: @WaelKhalifa i customized session.php file. 'cookie' => env('SESSION_COOKIE', env('APP_NAME').'_session'), and 'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', '.dadzan.com'), and   'http_only' => true, and     'same_site' => null,
    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

Comment: Could you please try to get auth user  `Auth::user()->id`

Comment: @WaelKhalifa is null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242761/discussion-between-d-motahhari-and-wael-khalifa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel session is initialized in a middleware so you can't access the session from a Service Provider, because they execute before the middleware in the request lifecycle

You should use a middleware to share your varibles from the session

However, If for some other reason you want to do it in a service provider, you can do it using a view composer with a callback, like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    //compose all the views....
    view()->composer('*', function ($view) 
    {
      auth()->user();
    });  
}
```

The callback will be executed only when the view is actually being composed, so middleware will be already executed and session will be available

Comment: It is done now and I can see the auth user in blade, thanks . but are you know how to login in controller  and get login user in appserviceprovider.php in laravel 9